# Помогите составить SQL запросы на выборку из двух таблиц по условию

Tags: vba, access, office

Логика запроса: вывести фамилию пациента имеющего максимальное число записей в таблице Обращения в текущем году. Среда выполнения MS ACCESS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И с чем у вас возникли сложности при выполнении задачи? Вы изучали язык запросов или сделайте-всё-за меня?

Comment: @AK застрял на стадии SELECT Персоны.Фамилия.

Comment: @AK и SELECT [Код персоны], MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM 
(SELECT [Код персоны], COUNT(*) FROM Обращения GROUP BY [Код персоны]) не срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил сам:

```
SELECT Код персоны
FROM Обращения 
GROUP BY Код персоны
HAVING COUNT(1) >= ALL(SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM Обращения 
GROUP BY Код персоны)
```